# ¿Cómo codificar condiciones múltiples en Java?

Tags: java, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente código que me devuelve si el valor es múltiple o no.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if((i%2)== 0){
        System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 2");
    }
    if((i%3)== 0){
        System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 3");
    }
    if((i%5)== 0){
        System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 5");
    }
    if((i%7)== 0){
        System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 7");
    }
    if((i%11)== 0){
        System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 11");
    }
}
```

Para imprimir en pantalla que no tiene ningún múltiple, ¿Cuál sería la condición?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

siguiendo tu codigo seria:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if((i%2)== 0 || (i%3)== 0 || (i%5)== 0 || (i%7)== 0 || (i%11)== 0){
    if((i%2)== 0){
        System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 2");
        }
    if((i%3)== 0){
            System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 3");
        }
    if((i%5)== 0){
            System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 5");
        }
    if((i%7)== 0){
            System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 7");
        }
   if((i%11)== 0){
            System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 11");
        }
}else{
System.out.println(i + " no es multiplo de nadie");
}
}
```

pero tambien lo puedes hacer swith

Answer (score 5):

Yo prefiero:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  boolean multiple = false;
  if ((i%2)== 0){
    System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 2");
    multiple = true;
  }
  if ((i%3)== 0){
    System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 3");
    multiple = true;
  }
  if ((i%5)== 0){
    System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 5");
    multiple = true;
  }
  if ((i%7)== 0){
    System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 7");
    multiple = true;
  }
  if ((i%11)== 0){
    System.out.println(i + " es multiple de 11");
    multiple = true;
  }
  if (!multiple) {
    System.out.println(i + " no es multiplo");
  }
}
```

O, mucho más legible

```
int dividendos[] = new int[]{2, 3, 5, 7, 11} {
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  boolean multiple = false;
  for (int dividendo : dividendos) {
    if ((i%dividendo) == 0){
      System.out.println(i + " es multiple de " + dividendo);
      multiple = true;
    }
  }
  if (!multiple) {
    System.out.println(i + " no es multiplo");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Todos los numeros son divisibles al menos por 1 y por el mismo. El caso mas extremo es cuando el numero es primo, para el cual tendrías que hacer un test de primalidad. En el caso de los numeros entre 1 y 100, basta con comprobar si es divisible por 2, 3, 5 o 7, los cuales son los primos menores o iguales que la raiz cuadrada de 100, pero para un caso mas general te recomiendo que uses un test de primalidad. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
bool isPrime(int n) {

    if(n < 2)
         return false;

    if(n == 2)
        return true;

    if(n % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i++)
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;

}
```